# print floats in ada

Tags: printing, floating-point, ada

I want to print a float number, i am using the package `FLOAT_IO`.

Is there a way to control the number of digits after the dot and before it?

Comment: It's great to know there are still people using this wonderful language!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The procedure `Put` in `Ada.Float_Text_IO` has three optional format-controlling parameters `Fore`, `Aft`, `Exp` that control the output. The meaning of these parameters is as follows:

- `Fore` denotes the number of digits (including the possible negative sign and leading zeros) before the dot;
- `Aft` denotes the number of digits after the dot (including any trailing zeros);
- `Exp` denotes the number of digits of the exponent (if necessary).

For a more thorough description and the default values of the format-controlling parameters see the [Ada 95 Reference Manual, section A.10.9](http://www.adahome.com/rm95/rm9x-A-10-09.html).

Comment: Can you explain what fore, aft, exp, stands for?

Comment: The reference manual section Ondrej linked to explains what Fore, Aft, and Exp are for.

Comment: Clarified a bit; however, it's a good idea to read the respective RM section to get familiar with the details.

Comment: @Doron Sinai - "fore" and "aft" are nautical terms for the front and back of the boat respectively. I guess this is one of those situations where not being a native English speaker can hurt you. "Exp" is just short for "Exponent".